# Would it be possible to open up textmate and multiple specific files at the same time?

Tags: textmate

I understand from bash I can do :

```
mate name/of/file.ext
```

And if I wanted to open up many files I can do :

```
mate name/of/file.ext other_file.rb some_file.txt
```

But what if I wanted to open an entire directory, and open up specific files as tabs as well?

Is there a command for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can in Textmate 2. For example, a directory containing many javascript files you can do:

```
mate javascripts/*.js javascripts
```

This will open all files ending in `.js` while also opening the `javascripts` folder explorer.

In Textmate 1, the same command will just add the folder and the files in the sidebar tray.